# Laravel 404 error with xampp

Tags: laravel

I am starting to learn how to work with laravel but got a problem. When I go to: http://localhost/testing/public/ I get a working page but when I typ for example http://localhost/testing/public/home which is one of my views I get a 404 error. Does someone know how to fix this?

Edit:
I am using the latest version of laravel and when I do for example:

```
Route::view('/home', 'home');
```

In my routes/web.php I get that error

Comment: One way would be to set up a domain the points to the public folder of your app https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#configuration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229126/using-domain-name-instead-of-localhost-in-with-https-in-xampp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more likely a problem with virtual Hosts, try the following:

- First edit your route to :`Route::get('/home', function(){echo
  "hello"});`
- Then try to access: `http://localhost/testing/public/index.php/home`

If it works then its certainly because you don't have a virtualHost, you can set it easily in your Xampp config and modifying ur hosts file

- First go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add a new
  line like: `127.0.0.1       yoursite.local`
- Then go to where xampp is installed under
  `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`
- Then add a virtual host in the bottom of the file like:

> `<VirtualHost *:80>`
>
> ```
> DocumentRoot "PATH_to_laravel_folder/public"  
>
> ServerName yoursite.local
> ```
>
> `</VirtualHost>`

- Then you can access your route by typing: `yoursite.local/home` or
  yoursite.local:80/home

**Hope it helps you guys :)**

Comment: Thanks works fine:) One last question when you have for example project.local/home it redirects you go google because he thinks it is invalide so you have to put http:// before it now is here a workaround for?

Comment: well you have to put the protocol which is http:// so the browser knows that this is an url and not something you're searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of routes.
after creating a view you have to add it in  `routes/web.php`

like `Route::view('/yourUrl', 'viewName');` in 5.5 version.
for 5.4 or older versions `Route::get('/yourUrl', 'viewName');`

after adding this to routes/web.php. you can access `http://localhost/testing/public/yourUrl`

you can find more [here](http://www.w3programmers.com/laravel-routes-definations/)

Comment: When I tried to use:Route::get('/about', function (){
    echo "<h2> This is About Page</h2>";
}); I still got a 404 error for example

Comment: @MrAndre I never face this error.
 can you tell me in which file you are add this .. ?

Comment: Added it in routes/web.php and Route::view('/home', 'home'); doesn't work for me have the latest version of lavarel

Answer (score 0):

If *http://localhost/testing/public/index.php/home* works, try to create a **.htaccess** file in **public** directory with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Run `$ composer install` in you command line

Comment: Please don't post "try this" answers. Either answer with confidence or otherwise post it as a comment (when you have enough points).