# Sublime text 3 on Zorin OS saved but the web page shows "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: apache, lamp

i created a hostname  to make it send to the page

[127.0.0.1 test.dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p13uP.png)

after creating it once i enter test.dev in the web address it is not redirecting me to the apache server page 
it is showing:
[This site can’t be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQllg.png)

how could i  get the localhost page

Comment: You probably need to add `test.dev` to your Apache virtual host config file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229126/using-domain-name-instead-of-localhost-in-with-https-in-xampp for an example

Comment: thank you i corrected it